# swiperjs - how to keep prev and next slider in sight but not centered current one

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

[image]
I'm using [swiperjs](http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.WTPU4ROGNcA), and what to stay part of the prev slider in the window, but not center the current one
I've tried`spaceBetween`, `centeredSlides` and `slidesOffsetBefore`, but none of these satisfied.
here is a  [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z33jqt4s/1/)
, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your swiping library adds a `swiper-slide-prev` to the previous slide.

Adding

```
.swiper-slide-prev {
  margin-left: 55px;
}
```

looks similar to what you want.
Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z33jqt4s/2/